# Should getters and setters used in pairs?

Tags: java, getter-setter, getter, setter, private-members

I am learning getters and setters in Java. I wrote the code below :

```
import java.util.*;
class test{
    private  int num1;
    private int num2;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    void mult(){
        num1=sc.nextInt();
        num2=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Multiply = "+(num1*num2));
    }
    
    public int getnum1(){
        return num1; 
    }
    
    public int getnum2(){
        return num2; 
    }
}

class TestDemo{
    void add(){
        test ob=new test();
        System.out.println("Num 1 = "+ob.getnum1());
        System.out.println("Num 2 = "+ob.getnum2());
        
    }
}
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        test ob=new test();
        ob.mult();
        TestDemo ob2=new TestDemo();
        ob2.add();
    }
}
```

Inside the class TestDemo, I am trying to access the value of the variables num1 and num2 but in the output, I am getting 0 as shown here:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9mBD.png)

Can anyone help me, how can I access the data inside the num1 and num2 inside TestDemo?

Comment: Hint: you're only setting those fields within the `mult()` method. In `TestDemo.add()`, you're creating a new instance and never calling `mult()`, so the fields will have their default values. The two instances of `test` that you've created are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass existing instance of test class to TestDemo instead of creating a new one. Like,

```
class TestDemo{
    private test ob;
    //set test instance through constructor or setter
   TestDemo(test ob) {
     this.ob=ob;
   }
    void add(){
        
        System.out.println("Num 1 = "+ob.getnum1());
        System.out.println("Num 2 = "+ob.getnum2());
        
    }
}
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        test ob=new test();
        ob.mult();
        TestDemo ob2=new TestDemo(ob);
        ob2.add();
    }
}
```